# Constructor and method error

Tags: java, methods

Can someone check where is wrong in this code?
The output should be true, but X is still false..

```
setOn(X , true);
System.out.println(X);
}

public static void setOn(boolean mode, boolean onValue) { 
    mode = onValue;
    }
public static boolean X = false;
```

I can't use X = onvalue, because I have other mode to use.

Comment: X itself is never set to true in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `setOn` receives a copy of `X` and sets *it* to `onValue`, but it doesn't change the original `X` variable.

But it doesn't even need `X` as a parameter, presumably because it's already in scope in the class that this code is in.  Just set `X` to `onValue` without the `mode` parameter.

```
public static void setOn(boolean onValue) { 
   X = onValue;
}
```

Comment: I can't x= onValue, I have like 2 more mode public static boolean A = true, etc

Comment: The presence of another variable `A` doesn't stop you from setting `X`.  If you have multiple `boolean` variables to set, then use a separate method for each, instead of attempting to write one method to set them all.

Comment: And anyway, since X is public, and the caller can access it directly, this method is completely useless. The caller can just use `X = true`.

Comment: but then I will have 3 similar method which I don't want. Is there a way to combine into one?

Comment: If you change it to private, how could the caller pass X to the method, since he wouldn't have access to it?

Comment: It would be possible to combine them into one method, but you would need some unrelated parameter to tell which variable to update, and that would be plenty more complicated.  It is easier and more understandable to have one very simple setter method for each variable that you would like to set.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't change the value of `X`, because `setOn()` receive a new copy of `X`. you should do something like this:

```
public static void setOn(boolean onValue) { 
    X = onValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer further:

1. if boolean is passed, then java works with Call by Value, because it is a basic data type.
2. if Boolean is passed, then java works with Call by Reference but since Boolean is immuatable it's actual value cannot be changed, but what we operate will be a new Wrapper instance of Boolean.

you can reproduce the same problem by passing String also. you will get a clear picture of immutability.

refer to java immutability and Wrapper classes and autoboxing.

http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/04/immutable.htm